# Extract time portion of Datetime2(7) in hhmmssfff format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, datetime

I need to extract the time portion of a datetime2(7) column in hhmmssfff format and I am doing it like this:

```
DECLARE @mdate AS DATETIME2(7) 

SET @mdate = '2012-03-15 10:13:27.5437431'

SELECT LEFT(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR ,@mdate ,114),':',''),'.',''),9)
```

Is there a better approach than doing this ugly replaces/convert/left?

I need this to join to a DimTime dimension whose key is in hhmmssfff format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Please don't use `varchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).
2. [Please use semi-colons as statement terminators](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons).
3. I don't think there is a more covert way to do this. Here is how I would do it (14 characters shorter, ignoring the semi-colon):

   ```
   DECLARE @mdate AS DATETIME2(7);

   SET @mdate = '2012-03-15 10:13:27.5437431';

   SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(TIME(3),@mdate),'.',''),':','');
   ```